# How to resize a UIScrollView to fit its contents? ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, resize

In my application( for iphone and ipad),I have

1.MPmoviePLayer
2.tableView
3.TextView
4.CollectionView,all in a single view

The number of entries in the tableView and CollectionView may vary.The textView may also have variable content depending upon the main data.

All the four views are added as subviews for a scrollView.I want the scrollView to automatically resize its height depending on the content.I want the app run in iOS versions from iOS 7.Is there a way to do that?Using autolayout may work fine in iOS 8.But i think it will not work in iOS 7.Any suggestion is accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tableview, collactionview , textView content size fixed ?

Comment: tableview and collectionview both have an imageview and a label.but for the textview the content may vary from a single line to a paragraph.

Comment: Do you have it working in iOS8? Have you thought of any approaches? Have you tried anything? What didn't work?

Comment: Actually this application was made by some other developer.So my project lead told me that it was working in ios8 but was not working in ios7.So ,now in this application,some hard coding is done to fit the content in the scrollview.I have to rebuild the page..any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

set below simple things in your appropriate method.

```
int height = CGRectGetHeight(tableview.frame)+CGRectGetHeight(CollectionView.frame)
             +txtview.contentSize.height;

scrolview.contentsize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height);
```

Comment: Where should i set this code?in the viewDidAppear?i used this code in viewdidappear.but the height of scrollview before and after setting this height remains the same.Do you know why?Thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

try this in your scrollViewDidScroll method...may be its work...

```
    self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollview.contentSize.width,self.scrollview.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: I don't think that this will change content size of scrollview, you get scrolview content size and provide it to it self..:)